# Wall Breakers - Rage Spell

Tags: clash-of-clans

Do wallbreakers have their damage increased while they are the Rage spell? I know that healers heal is amplified under the effect of Rage. Is there a way we can test it?

Answer (score 4):

Rage spell will increase all troops'es damage and heal, it just won't affect on other spells.

**From [wiki](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Rage_Spell) :**

> The Rage Spell creates a translucent purple ring on the battlefield
>   that boosts the movement speed and damage of any friendly units inside
>   the ring. In the case of Healers, the Rage Spell increases their
>   healing by a similar amount.

For test you can send a level 5 wall breaker toward some level 7 walls, he will destroy the wall with rage spell but he can't destroy it without the spell.